# How to redirect C:/xampp/htdocs/myfolder to C:/somewhere_else?

Tags: apache, xampp, directory

I installed XAMPP and have an apache server running. My files are located on C:/xampp/htdocs and are acessible from a www.mydomain.etc, but I would like www.mydomain.etc/foo to be read by C:/somewhere_else instead. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_alias and add this to httpd.conf:

```
Alias /foo c:/somewhere_else
```

Answer (score -1):

You just go into your httpd config file, which probably is located at something like this:

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

Open it, and do the following changes, change to your new directory.

```
Change the lines:
.
.
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
.
.
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
.
.
```

Restart Apache and xampp and you should be up and running.

Comment: Not this, sorry, I want to change one folder (for example, mysite is still on C:/xampp/htdocs, but mysite/foo spetially is on c:/foo).

Comment: Can you please clearify more exactly what the conditions are and what the problem is, please?